# Given positive $x$, $y$ and $\pi(x)$, what is a good heuristic for $\pi(xy)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Obviously $\pi(xy) = y \pi(x)$ when $y = 0$ or 1. But for almost any other nonnegative real value of $y$ it seems almost a certainty that $\frac{\pi(xy)}{\pi(x)}$ would fluctuate so that for $\pi(xy) = a \pi(x)$ it would hardly ever be the case that $a = y$.

For example, given $y = \frac{3}{2}$, a graph of $\frac{\pi(xy)}{\pi(x)}$ for values of $2 \leq x \leq 1000$ suggests that $$\pi\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \approx \frac{7}{5}\pi(x).$$

The only thing I can glean from Bertrand's postulate is that $\pi(2x) > \pi(x)$. My number crunching suggests that $a \approx \frac{7}{4}$ for $y = 2$.

Of the "similar questions" only [Conjecture : A lower bound for the prime counting function .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951341/conjecture-a-lower-bound-for-the-prime-counting-function) seems pertinent, but I'm not sure how.

My question is, given $\pi(xy) = a \pi(x)$, is there a way to get $a$ from $y$ without reference to $x$ such that $a \pi(x)$ gives a decent approximation of $\pi(xy)$?

Comment: Well the obvious thing would be to just plug in what $\pi(x)\approx x/\log(x)$ tells you.

Answer (score 3):

The prime number theorem says $\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x},$ which means, means for fixed $y>0,$ $$\frac{\pi(xy)}{\pi(x)}\sim y\cdot \frac{\log(x)}{\log(x)+\log(y)}\sim y$$

But for “small” $x,$ the prime number theorem can be far off, and $\frac{\log x}{\log x+\log y}$ can be very far from $1.$ For a small $y,$ though, the latter isn’t that big a deal at $x=1000.$ The real problem is the error in the prime number theorem.

So you might need larger $x$ to see it getting closer to $\frac32.$

When $x=10^{27}$ and $y=10,$ we can use the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) table of values of $\pi(\cdot)$ and compute: $$\frac{\pi(10^{28})}{\pi(10^{27})}\approx 9.637\\
\frac{y\log x}{\log (xy)} \approx 9.643$$